# Vector version of the proof that $\overline{X}$ and $S^2$ are independent

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Assume that $X'_i$s are i.i.d distributed as $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

There is a famous theorem that the sample mean $\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and the sample variance  $S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline{X})^2$ are independent.

I know there are already numerous answers about this theorem. Here I want ask a specific method of the proof.

Step1: Let $X=\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}'$, $\iota=\{1,1,...,1\}'$, $P=\iota(\iota'\iota)^{-1} \iota'$

Then, $\overline{X}= {1\over n} \iota' X$

Step2: $S^2= {1\over n-1} X'(I-P)X$

Step3: $S^2$ is a function of $(I-P)X$

Step4: $\iota' X$ and $(I-P)X$ are independent

Step5: Therefore, $\overline{X}$ and $S^2$ are independent.

In this method, I can understand step1 ~ step4. However, I cannot understand why step5 holds. Specifically, I don't know the logical bridge between step 3 and step5. Although $S^2$ is a function of $(I-P)X$, since $S^2$ is not multiplied by a constant with $(I-P)X$, can't we say that $\overline{X}$ and  $S^2$ are independent just because  $\overline{X}$ and $(I-P)X$ are independent?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $g(X)$ and $f(Y)$ are independent for any measurable functions $g$ and $f$.

Comment: Thank. @d.k.o. Actually, I cannot have confident that $S^2$ is a function of $(I-P)X$.  $S^2$ is a function of $(I-P)X$ and $X'$. Hence, how can I guarantee that if $(I-P)X$ and $Y$ are independent, $g((I-P)X, X')$ and $Y$ are independent? For example,  if $(I-P)X$ and $Y$ are independent, can we say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: @martian03 $I-P$ is idempotent, then $S^{2}=(n-1)^{-1}X^{\top}(I-P)X=(n-1)^{-1}\bigl((I-P)X\bigr)^{\top}\bigl((I-P)X\bigr)$ hence is a function of $(I-P)X$.

Comment: Thank you! @Q9y5, If you write this as an answer, I will select it correct answer.

Comment: Further question: For the step4, my manual uses the fact that $E[(I-P)X(\iota'X)']=0$. However, I cannot understand how this can guarantee independence of $(I-P)X$ and $(\iota' X)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $P\equiv \iota(\iota^{\top}\iota)^{-1}\iota$, it's symmetric and we have $P^{2}=\iota(\iota^{\top}\iota)^{-1}\iota=P$, meaning it's *idempotent*. Using this result, we deduce $(I-P)(I-P)=I-P-P+P^{2}=I-P$, thus $I-P$ is also idempotent.

Therefore,
$$S^{2}=(n-1)^{-1}X^{\top}\underbrace{(I-P)}X=(n-1)^{-1}X^{\top}\underbrace{(I-P)(I-P)}X=(n-1)^{-1}\bigl((I-P)X\bigr)^{\top}\bigl((I-P)X\bigr),$$
hence a function of $(I-P)X$.

---

Update for your question:
Note that $(I-P)X$ and $\iota^{\top} X$ are all normal distributed, hence uncorrelated$\iff$independent.
$$
\mathrm{Cov}\bigl((I-P)X,\iota^{\top}X\bigr)=\mathbb{E}[(I-P)X(\iota^{\top}X)]-\mathbb{E}[(I-P)X]\mathbb{E}[\iota^{\top} X]=0-(I-P)\mu(\iota^{\top}\mu)=0.$$